# Unable to retrieve header field SenderCompID , 142 from de-serialized Quickfixj Quote messase

Tags: serialization, quickfix, fix-protocol

Our FIX Engine implemented in QuickfixJ send the received quote message in the quote session to another application listening on JMS queue for further processing like persistig to DB. 
The message serialized and de-serialized using Apache serializationUtils.

The problem is, the application throws FieldNotFound error when it attempts to retrieve SenderCompId header field from the de-serialized message. 
    setSenderlocid(header.getField(new SenderLocationID()).toString())

```
quickfix.FieldNotFound: Field [142] was not found in message.
at quickfix.FieldMap.getField(FieldMap.java:216)
at quickfix.FieldMap.getFieldInternal(FieldMap.java:353)
at quickfix.FieldMap.getField(FieldMap.java:349)
```

Does serialization work with QuickFixJ messages?

Comment: How do you initialize your `header` object ? I believe your header isn't being initalized properly ?

Comment: Can we see a little more code before the getField call?

Comment: DumbCoder & Grant, our counterparty says that they are not sending this field in the message. Thanks for you time.